# Qt 5.5.1: Using qDebug() in a template

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem:

I'm using Qt 5.5.1 and use the qDebug() function to generate log files via the internal message (qInstallMessageHandler) handler. In this message handler, there is a specific message pattern:

```
[%{time yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.zzz} %{if-debug}DBG%{endif}%{if-info}INF"
                    "%{endif}%{if-warning}WRN%{endif}%{if-critical}CRT%{endif}%{if-fatal}FTL%{endif} %{category}]"
                    " %{file}:%{line} - %{message}
```

This results in message like:

```
[2017-07-17 13:52:57.934 INF default] ..\..\..\file.cpp:146 - OutputTxt
```

Normally, there should be an output with relativ paths, but some messages are with an absolute path. I found out that when I use qDebug() in a template-function results in that "problem" with the absolute paths.

Does someone know, how I can use qDebug() in a template function, so that I have relative paths in my message handler?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use qDebug in a template function so it's probably not because of the template. Can you give us a simple code with the error, then we will be able to test it.

Answer (score 1):

[QMessageLogger](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qmessagelogger.html#details) actually generates the logging messages. From the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qmessagelogger.html#details):

> `qDebug()` expands to `QMessageLogger(__FILE__, __LINE__, Q_FUNC_INFO).debug()` for debug builds, and `QMessageLogger(0, 0, 0).debug()` for release builds.

There are two consequences to this:

1. File, line number, and function name are only available in debug mode [by default.](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qmessagelogcontext.html#details)
2. The file path printed by your message handler depends on the preprocessor's expansion of the `__FILE__` macro.  Whether that file path is relative or absolute may be dependent on your compiler's preprocessor.

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) has this to say about the `__FILE__` preprocessor macro:

> This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the path by which the preprocessor opened the file, not the short name specified in ‘#include’ or as the input file name argument. For example, "/usr/local/include/myheader.h" is a possible expansion of this macro.

With this information, here is a minimal example showing why calling Qt's debugging functions from a template function might print absolute paths:

### warn.h

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void warn(const T& message)
{
      qWarning() << message;
      std::cerr << "Macro __FILE__ expands to:  " << __FILE__ << std::endl;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include "warn.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qSetMessagePattern("File: %{file} Message: %{message}");
    warn("OutputTxt");
}
```

And this gives the expected output using relative paths:

```
File: ./warn.h Message: OutputTxt
Macro __FILE__ expands to:  ./warn.h
```

But if we move `warn.h` to another directory (`/var/tmp`) and add the new location of the file to our .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /var/tmp/
```

We get this output with absolute paths:

```
File: /var/tmp/warn.h Message: OutputTxt
Macro __FILE__ expands to:  /var/tmp/warn.h
```

Similarly, if we include the header file with our template function using an absolute path in main.cpp rather than appending to `INCLUDEPATH`:

```
#include "/var/tmp/warn.h"
```

We also get output with absolute paths:

```
File: /var/tmp/warn.h Message: OutputTxt
Macro __FILE__ expands to:  /var/tmp/warn.h
```

So while it may just be a quirk of your compiler's preprocessor, it might also be how you are including the header file containing your template function.  If you are not explicitly including this header file using an absolute path, you can check your qmake generated Makefile's `INCPATH` variable to see if there are any absolute include paths.